# If conditional not working in jQuery each function

Tags: jquery

Here is my html:

```
<div>
  <li>
    <a href="#">link</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">link 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">link 3</a>
  </li>
</div>
```

This jQuery code is working fine:

```
$("div li").each(function() { 
    $('a', this).wrapInner("<span></span>");
});
```

However this breaks the code and nothing happens at all.

```
$("div li").each(function() {   
    $('a', this).wrapInner("<span></span>");        
        if $('span', this).height() > 10 {
            $(this).addClass('newClass');
        }

    });
```

What I need to happen is after the span is inserted into the link, I need the span's height to be measured and if its over 10px then for its containing li to have a class of newClass to be applied to it.

Comment: call $('a span', this)

Comment: Are the missing parentheses around the `if` expression a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($('span', this).height() > 10) {
        $(this).addClass('newClass');
    }
```

you need to have your if statement condition wrapped in parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$("div li").each(function() {   
$('a', this).wrapInner("<span></span>");        
    if ($('a span', this).height() > 10) {
        $(this).addClass('newClass');
    }

});
```

Comment: With the given HTML there's really no difference between using `'a span'` and just `'span'`.

Comment: There are no spans to begin with. The call to `$('a', this).wrapInner("<span></span>");` adds a `<span>` element around the content of the `<a>` element. In the context of `this` (an individual `<li>`) the only `<span>` element is going to be inside the `<a>` element, so `'a span'` and `'span'` will select the same elements.

Comment: $('a', this).wrapInner("<span></span>"); see this...??this will represent "div li" and the wrapInner will wrap after the anchor tag...see the first example in http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/

Comment: If you have this HTML: `<li><a><span>Text</span></a></li>` then these two selectors - `'li a span'` and `'li span'` - will select the exact same element - the only `<span>` that is present! In the case of this code, `this` is the `<li>` element; there's only one span to select, you don't **need** to specify that it's inside the `<a>`, because it's still inside the `<li>`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no span in this code:

```
$("div li").each(function() {   
    $('a', this).wrapInner("<span></span>");        
        if $('span', this).height() > 10 {
            $(this).addClass('newClass');
        }
});
```

so you will need to apply the span first, the select from "this" to find it:

```
$("div li").each(function() {   
    $('a', this).wrapInner("<span></span>");        
    if ($(this).find('a span').height() > 10) {
        $(this).addClass('newClass');//adds the class to the li by the way.
    }
});
```

Comment: What are you on about when you say "There is no span in this code"? The line above the `if` statement adds the span...

Comment: Probably just my bad comment form, that function never executes as there is a syntax issue with the conditional, mere passing this through jshint highlights that issue.  I made a slight modification to the form, but the effect should be the same really.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your if condition in braces, like this :

```
$("div li").each(function() {   
$('a', this).wrapInner("<span></span>");        
    if ($('span', this).height() > 10) {
        $(this).addClass('newClass');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Ux2z/

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the condition on the `if` statement in parentheses:

```
if ($('span', this).height() > 10) {
    $(this).addClass('newClass');
}
```

If you haven't already (and it sounds like you haven't) I'd suggest learning how your browser's developer tools work - if you're using Firefox, [install Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) - so you can do this kind of basic JavaScript debugging for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **the breaks ()** in if condition

```
$("div li").each(function() {   
    $('a', this).wrapInner("<span></span>");        
        if ($('span').height() > 10) {
            $(this).addClass('newClass');
        }

});
```

Also your are missing ul tag before and after **li**s

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="#">link</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">link 2</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">link 3</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Not tested.